# Check fake flash drives and set them to their real sizes

Tags: bash, usb-drive, posix

I have a couple hundred of "fake" flash drives; The kind you would see on online store, with false/questioning sizes, like "1TB" or "1ZB"...

How do i know they are "fake"? They basically stop the transfer of files after some point, where they basically fail and the OS where the transfer happen usually show an error.

Now i did manage to check for the real size of such flash drive, and set them to their real size, a while ago (couple years ago, so i don't remember the *exact* procedure), but i did so:

- Fill flash drive until error come up, and note down/print the actual/exact size of said data when the error comes up (since it would indicate the *real* size of said flash drive).
- "format" the flash drive to it's real size, by using `dd`.

I'm already partially aware on how to do the first part. The problem comes at the second part, which I'm not entirely sure how it is done, though i do remember that back then, when i did it, i used `dd` to write an empty image file i created, of the exact, real size of the flash drive, and used `dd` with it.

Some might think/argue that, "it is useless" or "the effort outweigh the result", which might be true if i only had one or two of these, but given that i always can find a use for these flash drives, even if not practical (due to the amount), it doesn't mean it's useless.

It is also possible given i managed to do it once, though i forgot about it...(and others probably managed to do something similar, though i didn't find any such examples on linux)

I don't have any data on these, and i also do not care if they break (given the amount i have) but i would still prefer setting them to their real size, as previously stated.

I basically want to do all of this with `bash`, `dd`, and some other Posix utilities.

Comment: Maybe you used `fdisk`? Because `dd` to change the partition table is not going to be easy...

Comment: I think yeah. But as mentioned, the memory of that time is fuzzy, beside what i mentioned in my post...wish i took notes :/ @AlexisWilke

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the tool [f3](http://oss.digirati.com.br/f3/) for this. It is a linux-port of [H2testw (german)](https://www.heise.de/ct/artikel/c-t-Systeminfo-2859100.html).

F3 is included in most major Distributions like debian, ubuntu and fedora

EDIT: you cannot fix the size of the stick/card/whatever without changing the firmware which is not a trivial task. But f3 provides the command f3fix which creates a partition with the real size of the stick so you cannot “overcommit” data by accident.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `dd` (`badblocks` in read-write mode with a test pattern could be a much better option) to wipe them and write down the real size.
2. Use fdisk/gdisk/sfdisk/cfdisk/whatever to create a single partition of the right use. Most of them can be trivially automated - probably the easiest one would be `sfdisk /dev/device < partition_table_file`.

Comment: I’d be cautious about using dd to find out the real size. Many of these fakes will successfully write to the end of their reported size.  They do it by mapping the same physical area to multiple addresses.  So dd would just keep writing.  You often have to read back in some way.

Comment: I noticed that too on some of mine. Some doesn't show any error even when exceeding the actual real size, and then, if i plug/replug or mount/remount the said drive, it would show non-existent file or some of the file i transferred would be deleted. @PhilipCouling

Comment: mind giving an example so i can test it? Just that providing example/code to do it would help better :)

Comment: @PhilipCouling `badblocks` then? ;-)

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I doubt it.  The trouble is each individual block will write and immediately read back.  It's just that some will overwrite each other. I suspect badblocks will not write everything and then read everything.

Comment: OK then, write `0x55` pattern over the entire disk and try to read as much. Must work :-) which is actually what I've edited my answer to.

Comment: As long as that pattern is changing between blocks that should be fine.  You could try to write a [massive random file](https://pinetools.com/random-file-generator) to it and then read back to see if the result matches.

Comment: I don't believe these fake drives have such an advanced controller it will be able to manage anything but zeros being written to it, so I'm almost sure a pattern will be enough but writing a comparing a randomly generated file is a 100% guarantee, you're right.

Comment: you all guys don't understand that nand flash is not hard drive. all your tools are just interactions on upper level (block device file system) while actually physical access is completely managed by lower firmware which takes care of wear-leveling (transition layer) which is like kind of controller for hard drives

Comment: https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory_controller